# How to register domain name on my local dns programmatically in java?

Tags: java, dns, virtualization

I'm writing a tool for provisioning of virtual machines. One task is when machine is up and running it need to get the host name from DNS for that it I need to register its ip there. Is there is a way how to do it programmatically in java?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions.

1. If the machines don't need special names, but can just be allocated an arbitrary DHCP lease, then you can give each possible address a fixed name, based on the address. You have probably seen many ISPs do this for their DSL customers so e.g. 82-69-170-87.dsl.in-addr.zen.co.uk is IP address 82.69.170.87 This option is very painless because it doesn't require anything special of the newly provisioned virtual machine or the provisioning system.
2. Use TSIG to do Dynamic DNS. Check that your DNS server supports TSIG based dynamic DNS and read its manual for how to authorise machines to perform updates. On many Unix systems you can use bind's *nsupdate* tool to perform dynamic updates with TSIG, but if you wish to do it in pure Java you will want to look at http://www.dnsjava.org/ which should have everything you need. This will involve considerably more work, but allows you to arrange for each VM to be named and assigned a specific address based on whatever rules you care to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're asking but I think you might be asking how to get the host name of the local machine once it is up?  i.e. a reverse DNS lookup?

If so then you can do it like this:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
```

This will return the hostname of the current machine mapped to the LAN IP as a String.